# QueryInterface and IntPtr in C# Syntax

Tags: c#, .net, syntax, com, marshalling

I am trying to use `InteropServices.Marshal.QueryInterface` to convert a COM object to a specific type in C#, but I am having trouble to pass in the first and last parameters.

I am assuming that `IntPtr` is a reference, but I cannot get `IntPtr` to reference my classes to use QueryInterface due to syntax errors.

Of course, the code that is shown below does not have the correct syntax, but it gives you an idea of what I am trying to do.

```
set
{
    ClassA a;
    Guid guid = Guid.Parse("XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX");
    System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.QueryInterface(ref value, 
        ref guid, out a);
}
```

EDIT:

```
[ComVisible(true), Guid("XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX")]
public ClassA : COMInterface{ ... }
```

ClassA is the C# class, and `COMInterface` is the COM interface. It is the only class that implements `COMInterface`. `value` in the `set` scope is the reference to the COM Interface, `COMInterface`

Comment: Is the type in C# an interface?  Does the COM object implement that interface?  Can you show the definition of the interface?

Comment: `ClassA` is the C# class, and it implements a `COMInterface`, which is the COM interface. It is the only class that implements the COMInterface. The value is the reference to the COM interface.

Comment: What do you mean by "put an interface between"?  That doesn't make sense.

Comment: I meant `ClassA` : `InterfaceB`, and `InterfaceB` : `COMInterface`. Ya, never mind.

Comment: This is really a duplicate of yesterday's http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12557544/trouble-casting-com-object-to-a-c-net-class

Comment: @Chris Dickson Yes, I came across `QueryInterface` and wanted to test the function out if it achieves my requirement, but I am having some problem using it due syntax. I guess that doesn't work either. :/

Comment: @ChrisDickson I agree, it's a duplicate, but I can't really close it, since I've answered it already.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not going to be able to do this.

The `IntPtr` that you have is a pointer to the implementation of the `COMInterface`.  It's perfectly feasible that you could have a *completely separate class* implementing `COMInterface` and that's what you're holding a pointer to.

That said, the call to `QueryInterface` can only be used to get a reference to the .NET representation of `COMInterface`, not an instance of `ClassA`; it would require you to shape the contents of the class implementing `COMInterface` in unmanaged code into something that managed code can understand and then write it to `ClassA` which is a completely different thing altogether.

Comment: Is it possible to put an interface, say `InterfaceB`, between `COMInterface` and `ClassA`. Is it possible to cast the COMObject to `InterfaceB`?

Comment: @swtdrgn What do you mean by "put an interface between"? That doesn't make sense.

Comment: Could you explain what are you trying to achieve? forcing an interface into a class makes no sense with or without COM. Imagine normal C# implementation of interfaces and classes - if you would have an `ILog fileLog` interface instance implemented by `FileLog` class, and you call `ConsoleLog l = (ConsoleLog)fileLog` what would you expect?

Comment: I was planning to write a self-wrapping class, and the first created instance comes back to this class (of a different instance).